# IE9 image border

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

[image]

That's a screenshot of my blog on Tumblr, on Chrome those black borders aren't existent, both images are PNG with a transparent background, how can I make those ugly boxes disappear? I've already tried following a few threads here on the subject, and they didn't work.

Hmmmm. That's really strange, Snipping Tool didn't capture the black boxes, but print screen did. here's the print screen image.

[image]

Comment: Add some HTML and CSS please.

Comment: Here's my whole webpage. How do I add my code? it's saying there's too many characters.

Comment: Here's my code.               http://pastebin.com/0AHgfZxS

Comment: Sorry but I see nowhere a link. Please just edit/add some helpful stuff to you question not the whole page. You may also put you stuff on http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @Rekire I would, I really want to help you help me,but I'm not exactly a web developer, I've picked up all this stuff from guides and just looking at the code, I'm not sure what you specifically want me to post.

Comment: Please wait for a while i have just now a meeting

Comment: I think this is what you were asking for @Rekire


http://pastebin.com/pT30eq3Y

Ok, well my code is waiting on the pastebin link I sent you, thanks for trying to help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details that is hard to say did you try to add this css?

```
img {
  border:none;
}
```

Comment: Nope, img {
  border:none;
}                       didn't work, I added it right before Body { and right after my @Font-face code.

Comment: Hey, I closed my blog, and reopened it in IE9, and after adding that img { border:none;} it now works... I think that fixed it. :)